# Filter ObservableCollection when button toggled

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

Currently I have a `ObservableCollection<Car> CarList`, a `WrapPanel`, and a `ToggleButton`. The `WrapPanel` contains some `CarInfo` user control, each `CarInfo` refers to a `Car` in the `CarList`.

Basically, when a new `Car` is added to `CarList`, a new `CarInfo` control should be added to `WrapPanel`. When the `ToggleButton` is clicked, the `WrapPanel` should only display `CarInfo` in which `Car.Speed > 70`.

I'm now subscribe to `CarList.CollectionChanged` to update the `WrapPanel`, and using `ICollectionView` to do the filtering.

My problem is: how can I trigger the filtering on `ToggleButton` click?

I'm really new to WPF, so some sample code is highly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be binding the WrapPanel's ItemsSource to the car collection rather than updating it manually.

To toggle the filter, add this event handler to your toggle button:

```
    private void toggleFilter_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CarList);
        if (toggleFilter.IsChecked == true)
            view.Filter = car => ((Car)car).Speed > 70;
        else
            view.Filter = null;
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem directly, but gave me useful insights on solving the original problem. Thanks :D